# NodeJS - Send result of a database query to a view or route before render

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, socket.io, handlebars.js

I'm making a webapp with NodeJS using Express JS, Socket IO and Handlebars, but i am pretty new to these technologies.

I'm struggling to find a way to pass the result from a query to my menu(a partial), mainly because Node is async, so by the time the result from my query returns, the page has already rendered, and the values never passed.

*main.handlebars (Main layout):*

```
(...)
{{> menu}}
(...)
{{{body}}}
```

*router.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var index_controller = require('../controllers/index_Controller');

router.get('/', index_controller.index);
module.exports = router;
```

*index_controller.js*

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {    
     res.render('main_page_html');
};
```

This menu will appear in every page, and i want to show in this menu names from people online, that it's the result from the query.

I tried putting the code for the query inside the route function, and it works, but i would have to copy the same code to every route that i have, because as i said, this menu appears in all of them.

If i try to do a function outside the route function, async kicks in and no data is sent to the page.

There's definitely a better solution for this.

P.s.: Emit my data via socket to the client is one way, but i would like to do things server-side.

**-Solution-**

I did as Tolsee said, i created a middleware, so now i can call this middleware in every route that is needed. This is how i have done:

*menu.js*

```
exports.onlineUsers = function (req, res, next) {
// database query {
//     res.locals.onlineUsers = queryResult;
//     next();
// }
}
```

*router.js*

```
var menu_midd = require('../middleware/menu');

router.get('/', menu_midd.onlineUsers, index_controller.index);
module.exports = router;
```

*index_controller.js*

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {    
     res.render('main_page_html',  {data: res.locals.onlineUsers});
};
```

Well, at least works for me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to this problem. If you want to do it server side then you need to pass the menu data to `handlebar/view`. If you want it through all the pages then you can make a `middleware` function and employ it to all the router like below:

```
function middleware(req, res, next) {
    // your code
    // define your menu variable
    // And assign it to res.locals
    res.locals.menu = menu
    next()
}

// let's employ it to all the routes 
app.use(middleware)

// You can employ it to separate routes as well
myRouter.get('/sth', middleware, function(req, res) {
    // your code
})
```

With that being said, If your menu is showing online users, you will need to use `socket.io`(even if you rendered it through server-side at the start) because you will need to update the online user list in real-time.